# Sceneform - increasing the default light node intensity?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

The Scene for sceneview has a default sun node attached to it. How can I increase the intensity of it without changing the color? Or if someone knows the default color of the light I can use `scene.setLightEstimate(DEFAULT_COLOR, 1f);`

Bump, I still can't figure out how to increase the default lighting intensity of the sun node

Answer (score 0):

```
scene.sunlight?.light?.intensity = 200f
```

See [the javadoc for Light](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/Light#setIntensity(float))